# Trying to connect MVC app to remote host at IP xxxxxxxxx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, api

I have been trying to connect my MVC app to a remote host at IP xxxxxxx.

but what the error i am gettting is this :

```
"InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)",
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "FATAL: 28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"210.7.22.121\", user \"user\", database \"postgres\", SSL off",
        "ExceptionType": "Npgsql.NpgsqlException",
        "StackTrace": "   at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.<ProcessBackendResponses>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.ProcessAndDiscardBackendResponses(NpgsqlConnector context)\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectedState.Startup(NpgsqlConnector context, NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open()\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.GetPooledConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection)\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestPooledConnectorInternal(NpgsqlConnection Connection)\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection)\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlServices.UsingPostgresDBConnection(NpgsqlConnection connection, Action`1 action)\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)"
```

But that ip 210.7.22.121 is my localmachine IP and it is also displaying the database name incorrectly.   I am trying to connect my MVC app to this remote host on IP xxxxxx :

Below is my web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" 
type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ibp_live3" connectionString="server=xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx;user id=xxxxx;password=xxx;database=xxxx" providerName="Npgsql" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>

    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />

    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.12.0" newVersion="2.0.12.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
   </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>




</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your DB is listening on that interface?

Comment: The error message is clear: `... no pg_hba.conf entry for host ...` That means the server has no configuration to accept connections from your IP. By default, PostgreSQL is configured by whitelisting, not blacklisting. This means you have to add allowed clients into the `pg_hba.conf` file as described here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Thanks i have asked the server host admin to white list my local machine IP. will advise if it works